# Spreading a character string by \n and putting dates as the observations

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
 [1] "\nCEO\n"                                       "2015 - Present"                                "\nSome text here that should be in a column\n"
 [4] "1995 - Present"                                "\nSome more text\n"                            "2012 - 2015"                                  
 [7] "\nCTO , project manager\n"                     "2006 - 2015"                                   "\nAnother project manager\n"                  
[10] "1998 - 2005"                                   "\nProject manager programming\n"               "1993 - 1998"                                  
[13] "\nSystems Admin\n"                             "1991 - 1993"                                   "\nProfesor\n"                                 
[16] "1991 - 1993"                                   "\nSome more text\n"                            "1988 - 1990"
```

I would like to convert it into some columns where the `\n` are the column names and below it are the dates.

Expected output:

```
CEO                Some text here that should be in a column      Some more text   CTO, project manager
2015 - Present       1995 - Present                                 2012- 2015         2006 - 2015
```

So the text with `\n` are the columns and the dates are the observation in that column.

Data:

```
d <- c("\nCEO\n", "2015 - Present", "\nSome text here that should be in a column\n", 
"1995 - Present", "\nSome more text\n", "2012 - 2015", "\nCTO , project manager\n", 
"2006 - 2015", "\nAnother project manager\n", "1998 - 2005", 
"\nProject manager programming\n", "1993 - 1998", "\nSystems Admin\n", 
"1991 - 1993", "\nProfesor\n", "1991 - 1993", "\nSome more text\n", 
"1988 - 1990")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it,

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(
    transform(data.frame(vars = d[c(TRUE, FALSE)], vals = d[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), 
              vars = gsub('\n', '', vars, fixed = TRUE)), 
names_from = vars, values_from = vals)
```

Note that the example you share doesnt much your expected output since in the example you have two columns with `Some more text` which causes it to output different result

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the most elegant solution but it produces something close to what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(d,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Var
df$Var <- ifelse(grepl('\n',df$d),'V1','V2')
#Pivot
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Var) %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=d) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-id) %>%
  mutate(V1=gsub('\n','',V1))
#Format
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(df1),stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df2) <- df2[1,]
df2 <- df2[-1,]
```

Output:

```
df2
             CEO Some text here that should be in a column Some more text CTO , project manager
1 2015 - Present                            1995 - Present    2012 - 2015           2006 - 2015
  Another project manager Project manager programming Systems Admin    Profesor Some more text
1             1998 - 2005                 1993 - 1998   1991 - 1993 1991 - 1993    1988 - 1990
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
inds <- grep("\\n.*\\n",d)
data.frame(setNames(as.list(d[-inds]),gsub("\\n","",d[inds])),check.names = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
1 2015 - Present                            1995 - Present    2012 - 2015
  CTO , project manager Another project manager Project manager programming
1           2006 - 2015             1998 - 2005                 1993 - 1998
  Systems Admin    Profesor Some more text
1   1991 - 1993 1991 - 1993    1988 - 1990
```